# Can $\ell_p$ unit-balls have more than 4 nearest points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, analysis

For a certain $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ I would like to show the inequality
$$\|M x\|_{s'} \le \|x\|_s $$
where $\frac 1s+\frac1{s'}=1$ and $s\in[1,2]$.
(This is equivalent to bounding the induced norm $\|M\|_{s'\to s}$.)
I have that $M=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&a\end{bmatrix}$ has all positive values and $a\ge\max\{b,c\}$, so $M$ is positive semidefinite. I can thus think of this as comparing a unit ball to another unit ball, given a simple rotation, shearing and scaling of the axes.

W.log. I can assume $\|x\|_s=1$.
I have identified the four points in which the two unit-balls touch each other. (See the picture below for an example.)

I now want to prove that *the two balls can not touch each other in more than the four points* I have identified.

This seems to stem from the fact that $\ell_p$ unit-balls are somewhat "square", since e.g. hexagonal unit-balls could of course easily have more points of touch. I don't know how to formalize this "squareness" however.

I don't know if it is necessary that one of the norms is the dual norm to the other (i.e. $\frac 1s+\frac1{s'}=1$), but it probably is required that $s,s'\ge 1$.

Do you know of some way to formalize the above intuition? Or some topological lemma related to distances between balls like this?

[image: Example]